# Parametrize template by function name c++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Having the following functions

```
void print(int a) { cout << a << endl; }
void print(std::string a) { cout << a << endl; }
```

You can do the following template

```
template <class T> void printT(T a) { print(a); }
```

**Is there some mechanism to parametrize the function name?**
Something like this:

```
template <class T, class F> void anyT(T a) { F(a); }
```

I don't need to be a function template, just some mechanism to achieve the same.

Comment: Just for curiosity: Why do you want to do this? Isnt it nice to be able to write `print(x);`, where `x` can be `string` or `int`, instead of having to specify the type (i.e. `print<int>(x)` for `int` and `print<string>(x)` for strings) ?

Comment: @tobi303, you don't need to specify the template type in this case. The compiler can quite easily deduce it.

Comment: @tobi303 I know. It's just a toy example to introduce the problem and make things easier to who wants to help. I really hate when some people paste all the code when it is not really needed.

Comment: @StoryTeller I know, but this is the only difference to having two simple overloaded functions that I could spot.

Comment: @EdwinRodríguez True, but your problem is the opposite.  You have some narrow technical problem in a solution to a different issue.  And you asked about the narrow technical problem *without* providing the wider context.  Which means people have to guess at the wider context (what problem you actually want to solve) to generate a working solution to your technical problem.  A paragraph on your wider problem usually solves this issue (keep the narrow technical problem part as well!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could pass the caller as a function pointer that takes as input `T` like below:

```
template <class T> void anyT(T a, void(*f)(T)) {
  f(a);
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd256ceb831e3f75)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but perhaps it would be best to not specify the signature of the function and just have a template parameter for it instead.  That way the signature is allowed to be different (`const T&` for example) and functors would be allowed too.

Comment: Thanks!. Works perfectly.

Comment: On the flip side to my previous comment, spelling the signature out like this disambiguates function overloads without any additional syntax required, which is a plus.  Whether it's worth the restriction or not is dependent on the OP I guess.

Comment: @GuyGreer The down-voter down voted exactly the solution you're suggesting, see the first edit. I guess there will be haters...

Comment: I was going to just say 'lol' but that's too short a comment :P.  Anyway, if he doesn't own up and explain what he didn't like, all we can really do is ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the function as a parameter.

```
template <class T, class F>
void anyT(T a, F f) {
    f(a);
}
```

The advantage of this compared to passing a function pointer with templated argument type proposed by 101010, is that this works with function pointers as well as functors (instances of any type that implement `operator()` such as lambdas.

The disadvantage is that getting a function pointer of an overloaded function can be tricky in the context of freely templated parameter. You'd need to use

```
void (*f)(int) = print;
anyT(a, f);
```

Or alternatively, wrap it in a lambda as proposed by GuyGreer.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would go with 101010's solution, however you seem to not want to pass the function pointer as a function parameter, but rather only as a template parameter.  Here's how you can do that:

```
    #include <string>

    template <class T, void(*func)(T)>
    void anyT(T t)
    {
        func(t);
    }

    void print(int i){}
    void print(std::string s){}

    int main()
    {
        anyT<int, print>(1);
        anyT<std::string, print>("hello");
    }
```

Unfortunately, it means you have to specify the template parameters for the function every time, which is a drag.

The better solution I think would be to just use a generic template parameter and a lambda:

```
   template <class T, class F>
   void anyT(T t, F f)
   {
       f(t);
   }

   auto printT = [](auto i){print(i);}
   anyT(0, printT);
```

The lambda is necessary because passing `print` directly would be ambiguous, the compiler won't know if you mean `print(int)` or `print(std::string)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a useful macro:

```
#define OVERRIDES_OF(...) [](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto){ return __VA_ARGS__ (decltype(args)(args)...);}
```

the result is a stateless lambda that forwards to the token provided.

Use:

```
static const auto printT = OVERRIDES_OF(print);
```

now `printT` is an object that wraps all of the overrides of `print`.

Comment: You seem to be missing an `auto`.  Regardless, are you making the macro variadic to support things like `OVERRIDES_OF(f<1,2,3>)`?  I can't think of any other reason, but I figure I may as well ask.

Comment: @guygreer you can pass override sets around as single objects with this technique.  Instead of having to specify one override.

Comment: Override sets?  I'm not sure I understand

Comment: @guy `printT` is one (stateless) C++ object that represents every possible override or `print`.  Which you can then pass to an algorithm (like sort or whatever), and have the override resolution occur at the point of use, not passing it in.

Comment: I think you're answering a different question.  I simply asked why the macro was variadic, I don't see how that affects what you are talking about.

Comment: @guygreer oh: It is variardic because the C preprocessor does not understand C++.  So yes `foo<hello, 2>::bob` would be parsed as 2 tokens.  Which sucks.  So, we get `__VA_ARGS__` and solved.  Just something I do automatically, so didn't think of it when you said variardic.

Answer (score 0):

struggling to understand the rationale here. In c++14 we have lambdas with auto arguments. Will this solve it?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()  {


    int a = 1;
    std::string str = "string";

    auto print = [] (const auto& a) { std::cout << a << std::endl; };

    print(a);
    print(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the function using a function pointer:

```
template <class T> void anyT(T a, void(*F)(T)) { F(a); }
```

but then you cannot pass a lambda:

```
auto printStr = [](std::string a) { cout << a << endl; };
anyT(foo, printStr); // This won't compile
```

An alternative approach would be to use `std::function`:

```
template <class T>
void anyT(T a, std::function<void(T)> F) { F(a); }
```

or a a generic template parameter:

```
template <class T, class F>
void anyT(T a, F func) { func(t); }
```

This has a drawback that it cannot resolve overloaded functions, but you can use a helper function:

```
template<typename F>
std::function<F> make_function(F *funPtr) {
    return std::function<F>(static_cast<F*>(funPtr));
}
```

and call `anyT` like this:

```
string foo = "foo";
anyT(foo, make_function<void(std::string)>(&print));
```